# Why are compact complex manifolds Liouville?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

I know this is true but strangely can't find references.

Also, consider the trivial $n$-bundle over any connected compact manifold, does Liouville imply that all holomorphic sections are constant?

Consider the tautological bundle over a Grassmanian manifold. Does Liouville imply that the only holomorphic section is the zero section?

Comment: Does Liouvilles mean "bounded holomorphic functions are constants ?". Then it's clear : Let $f:X \to \mathbb C$ holomorphic. Then, $f$ is open, but $f(X)$ is compact, contradiction.

Comment: For the second question, the answer is also yes, and this follows immediately from exactly the same argument.

Comment: N.H. Yes, that is the definition. And I understood your comment. It is even easier than original theorem for the complex line.

Comment: @mariano A statement in an article I am reading says they're no holomorphic non trivial sections of the tautological bundle. That is ok. But it says they're plenty such sections in the dual bundle of the tautoligical bundle. I still can't see how that is possible, given that the dual is 'not so different'.

Comment: But that happens very very often, in fact! Just consider the canonical bundle on projective space and its dual. The computation is done in Hartshorne and many other places.

Comment: In the $C^\infty$ category, there is not much difference between a vector bundle and its dual, but in the algebraic/holomophic categories there is a world of difference. You should try to compute sections by hand on the tangent bundle on $P^1$ and its dual before continuing to read whatever paper it is you are reading.

Comment: Ok, I will try, but I will leave the following comment. The whole point of this question was trying to understand what is missing in order to be able to use Liouville to make the same implications as the previous ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: X \to \mathbb C$ an holomorphic map, non-constant

Then $f$ is open (standard argument using Maximum principle for example). But $f(X)$ is compact and open, and non-empty. Contradiction.

Conclusion : $f$ is a constant map.

Comment: It is not true that if $f:X\to\mathbb C$ is holomorphic then $f$ is open. This is only true if the function is non-constant, and  you cannot put the hypthesis in a parenthetical remark!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez you're totally right, I will edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$Let $M$ be a *connected* compact holomorphic manifold.

Chern's *Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory* gives a proof in the first few pages that every holomorphic function on $M$ is constant.

It follows that if $M \times \Cpx^{k} \to M$ is a trivial holomorphic vector bundle over $M$, then every holomorphic section is constant: A holomorphic section $s:M \to M \times \Cpx^{k}$ followed by projection to the second factor is a holomorphic map $M \to \Cpx^{k}$, and each component function of this map is constant.

Since the tautological bundle of a Grassmannian $G_{k}(V)$ may be viewed as a holomorphic subbundle of the trivial bundle $G \times V \to G$, the only holomorphic section of the tautological bundle is identically zero: By the preceding paragraph, every holomorphic section is constant, and by definition of the tautological bundle, the value of a section must lie in *every* $k$-dimensional subspace of $V$, hence must be the zero vector.